# Cannot get the POST request to work AlamoFire and XCode/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire

I am using Swift and Xcode and am trying to send a Post request. A normal request without parameters and no method declaration is working. However, when I try to do a specific post request with parameters it no longer works. I have taken the logic straight from Alamofire's documentation. I have included some pictures and code below.

[image: screenshot from XCode]

```
let parameters = ["barcdodeNumber": displayValue]
            
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
//this is the right way, but it does not work
            
AF.request(url).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
//this is wrong but it works
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What does "does not work" mean?  Do you get a response? An error? See [ask]

Comment: @Paulw11 So basically the first way (AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)) does not successfully send a request to our server. The second way does send a request to the server but it is not ideal because it only allows us to add one parameter as opposed to multiple

Comment: As Rob points out you need the `.response` - did you accidentally omit this from your question or is it missing from your real code too?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is missing in my real code as well. I am going to try the code in the answer below posted by Rob

Comment: Unrelated, but `barcdodeNumber`? Perhaps you meant `barcodeNumber`.

Comment: @Rob actually this was just a typo when we were naming our variables, good catch though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this was the way that ended up working correctly.

```
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: 
    URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).response { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
```

Comment: The inlcusion of the "encoding: 
    URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)" helped make everything work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call one of the `response` methods, e.g.,

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

This begs the question as to what your endpoint returns. Usually it’s JSON, so you’d use `responseJSON` or one of the decoder renditions.